# Failing "Route53 change failed to propagate" when deleting a CloudFormation stack

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

When I try to delete my CloudFormation stack it is now failing and I am getting the error "Route53 change failed to propagate". I have made no changes and I have been able to bring up and delete this stack many, many times without any issues then all of a sudden I am getting this error. Any clues on why this might have occurred out of nowhere and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have full route53:* IAM policy rights?

Comment: Yes. It was working with no issues and then all of a sudden this happened.